# How can I add transition to this show more category button that displays the li items that are hidden

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So basically I tried to show only 10 items by default and keep the rest hidden, which are visible on clicking more category div at the bottom. Done this with jQuery and now I want to add some transition to the toggle window which opens up promptly. Any guidance?

```
var max = 10;
jQuery('#menu-categories').each(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).find('li').length > max) {
        jQuery(this).find('li:gt(' + max + ')').hide().end().append('<li class="sub_accordian"><div class="show_more">More Categories</div></li>');


        jQuery(this).find('.sub_accordian').click(function (e) {
            jQuery(this).siblings(':gt(' + max + ')').toggle();
            if (jQuery(this).find('.show_more').length) {
                jQuery(this).html('<div class="show_less">Close Menu</div>');
            } else {
                jQuery(this).html('<div class="show_more">More Categories</div>');
            };
        });
    };
});
```

[View of the show more div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrlVx.png)

Comment: you mean animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one method that uses the css `transition`. When the page is loaded, jquery quickly determines the open and close height of the UL. It saves these variables into attributes that can be easily grabbed.

```js
var max = 3;
jQuery('#menu-categories').each(function() {
  let oh = 0;
  jQuery(this).find('li').each(function() {
    oh += +jQuery(this).height()
  })
  oh += jQuery(this).find('li').height()
  jQuery('#menu-categories').attr('open-height', oh);

  if (jQuery(this).find('li').length > max) {
    jQuery(this).find('li:gt(' + max + ')').hide().end().append('<li class="sub_accordian"><div class="show_more">More Categories</div></li>');
    jQuery(this).attr('close-height', jQuery(this).height())
    jQuery(this).css({
      height: jQuery(this).height(),
      visibility: 'visible'
    })

    jQuery(this).find('.sub_accordian').click(function(e) {

      jQuery(this).siblings(':gt(' + max + ')').toggle();
      if (jQuery(this).find('.show_more').length) {
        jQuery('#menu-categories').css('height', jQuery('#menu-categories').attr('open-height'))
        jQuery(this).html('<div class="show_less">Close Menu</div>').hide().fadeIn();
      } else {
        jQuery('#menu-categories').css('height', jQuery('#menu-categories').attr('close-height'))
        jQuery(this).html('<div class="show_more">More Categories</div>').hide().fadeIn();
      };
    });
  };
});
```

```css
#menu-categories {
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  transition: height .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='menu-categories'>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I found a simpler way to do it in javascript documentation. Used toggle function parameters. toggle("slow") and it did the job I was searching for